# System`Private`HasSubCodeQ broken in 11.2

Tags: core-language, undocumented

In 11.2 I was spelunking with `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal `` and noticed that everything seemed to have a `SubValues` kernel function.

This struck me as odd so I tried:

```
With[{s = Evaluate@Unique[sym]},
 s // System`Private`HasSubCodeQ
 ]

True
```

It seems `` System`Private`HasSubCodeQ `` is broken (which is a big pain for meta-programming).

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: I confirm the issue with version 11.2.0 on Win7 x64. ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal@a`` returns ``a[___][___] := <<kernel function>>;`` for undefined symbol `a` what is obviously a bug. Please report it.

Comment: This is undocumented functionality tho, so even if you report it, this would probably be low-priority.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov and b3m2a1, Can you reproduce the problem with documented functionality? If not I don't  agree it is a bug. The more that `With[{s = Evaluate@Unique[sym]}, SubValues@s]` behaves correctly and so does ``With[{s = Evaluate@Unique[sym]}, Language`ExtendedFullDefinition@s]`` which is used by top level functions. But yes, interesting question.

Comment: This is the issue with undocumented functionality, it may break your code in future and you are not supposed to blame anyone :) I'm removing [tag:bug] but will gladly revert that if WRI Support or someone familiar with internals confirms it.

Comment: @Kuba ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal`` uses this function. I don't know anything else that does. I don't know if we can call it a bug, per se, but Taliesin Beynon probably should know about this.

Comment: @b3m2a1 ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal`` is undocumented too soo :) Yep, bug may be a vague term. I don't mind tagging undocumented functions with [tag:bug] but there is no clue what is the purpose of ``System`Private`HasSubCodeQ`` except its name/'common sense'. Maybe it is a bug or by design. We will see.

Comment: @Kuba It's also private, which for me doubles the reason you give for not tagging it a bug without WRI input

Comment: @MichaelE2 Seems reasonable to me. I don't even know that this is something WRI *will* give input on, though. I'd doubt that it's common knowledge there that it exists.

Comment: This has been fixed in the development build today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed as of version 11.3.0:

```
With[{s = Evaluate @ Unique[sym]}, s // System`Private`HasSubCodeQ]

(* False *)
```

Comment: Great. My documentation generator will work again. I assume ``HasPrintCodeQ`` is also fixed?

Comment: Not quite sure, in what way was it broken?

Comment: Same way. I just checked and it's also working again.

Comment: Strange, does not seem broken in my 11.2.

Comment: Interesting. I've overwritten my 11.2 with 11.3 but I was pretty sure it was feeding me spurious results.